# Displaying texture in android using OPENGL ES 2.0 AND SDL 2.0 in c(native code)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, sdl-2

I am trying to display texture in android screen using OPENGL ES 2.0 library along with SDL 2.0.Since i am getting frames from ffmpeg,it was suggested that using OPENGL library we can reduce the delay during texture updation.Now i am having my frames ready to update the screen.So can anyone tell me how to display those raw frames from ffmpeg to android display?Here is my sample code where i got problem,i don't know how to proceed after this.

```
SDL_Window  *screen=0;
SDL_GLContext   maincontext=0;
SDL_Surface *image=NULL;
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) {
    LOGD( "Could not initialize SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(1);
}
LOGD(" SDL Initialized..");
//OPENGL intialization:-
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION,3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION,0);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER,1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE,24);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL,1);
//SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_SHARE_WITH_CURRENT_CONTEXT,0);

screen =    SDL_CreateWindow("Window",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,0,0,SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN|SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL|SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
LOGD("SDL Screen Created ..");

//image=SDL_LoadBMP("img.bmp");
maincontext=SDL_GL_CreateContext(screen);
/* Clear our buffer with a red background */
    glViewport(0,0,240,240);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Did you get your answer? I am having similar type of issue.

Comment: @AndroEmbedded No i didn't got the answer yet.So i tried with java+opengles1(Native),and i got the texture successfully updated.